# ASP.NET MVC 4 SPA how to remove redirect to the login page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, single-page-application

We are working with SPA (MVC 4 + angularjs) site and we want to deny access for static files for unauthorized visitors. 
Currently all requests to this static files ended up with redirect to the login page. We want to recieve 401 or 403 error code instead. This files also could be requested with ajax.

Root **web.config**:

```
    <authentication mode="None">
    </authentication>
```

**Web.config** in the static files folder:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <clear/>
      <add type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" path="*" verb="*"  name="StaticFileHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I wonder how we could deny access to static files for unauthorized visitors (withot redirect to the login page)?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I posted answer below, later I will upload somewhere web project template of SPA based on angularjs+WebApi, with authentication/authorization against MongoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with this solution:

1. Add *web.config* to the static files folder.

   > ```
   > <configuration>
   >   <system.web>
   >     <authorization>
   >       <deny users="?"/>
   >     </authorization>
   >   </system.web>
   >   <system.webServer>
   >     <handlers>
   >       <clear/>
   >       <add type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" path="*" verb="*"  name="StaticFileHandler"/>
   >     </handlers>
   >   </system.webServer>
   > </configuration>
   > ```
2. Add special module (in the site root *web.config*) that suppresses redirects to the login page.

> ```
> <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">   
>   <add 
>     name="SuppressRedirect" 
>     type="Web.Common.Modules.SuppressRedirectModule, Web.Common"/>
> </modules>
> ```

And the module code below

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace Web.Common.Modules
{
    public class SuppressRedirectModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.AuthenticateRequest += this.OnEndRequest;
        }

        private void OnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
            context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```